# Service stack arrayof to be removed

Tags: servicestack

I have my dto defined as

```
[DataContract(Name = "Tuner", Namespace = "")]
public class TunerDto
{
     [DataMember(Name = "TunerName", Order = 1)]
    public string TunerName { get; set; }
}
```

and I am returning an array of theses which gives my XML in the body as:

```
 <ArrayOfTuner>
    <Tuner>
       <Name>Test1</Name>
    </Tuner>
    ...

 </ArrayOfTuner>
```

Is there a way of replacing ArrayOfTuner with Tuners instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap your array in a class, so you can add a `[CollectionDataContract]` attribute to modify the serialization output:

```
[CollectionDataContract(ItemName = "Tuner")]
public class Tuners : List<TunerDto>
{
    public  Tuners() { }
    public  Tuners(IEnumerable<TunerDto> collection) : base(collection) { }
}
```